# oscillatory integrals in several variables with nonstationary pahse

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the oscillatory integral

$$I(\lambda):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \mathrm{e}^{\lambda\dot{\imath}\phi{(x)}} \psi{(x)}dx $$
where the phase $\phi$ and the amplitude $\psi$ are smooth real-valued functions and $\psi$ has compact support.

If the phase $\phi$ is not stationary in the support of $\psi$ then

$$I(\lambda)=O(\lambda^{-N})\label{1}\tag{1}$$

for all $N\geq 0$.

The phase is stationary at the point $x_{0}$ if
$$
(\nabla \phi)(x_{0})=0.
$$
In practice, one may need to know the exact contribution of the derivatives of $\phi$ and $\psi$ to the asymptotic \eqref{1}.
The coefficients in the one dimensional case can be easily calculated. It can be immediately seen that the factor ${1}/{\phi^{\prime}}$ plays an important role.

The question is:

Does any one know how precisely the implicit constant in the asymptotic \eqref{1} depends on the derivatives of $\phi$ and $\psi$ and the support of $\psi$ ?

Any reference ?

Comment: The question pertains the researches of Lars Hörmander, Francois Treves and others: while I do not know a precise answer to the question, I can suggest you the two following monographs, where, I bet, you can find an answer: [1] Lars Hörmander (1985), *The analysis of linear partial differential operators. IV: Fourier integral operators*, , Springer-Verlag, MR0781537, Zbl 0612.35001, [2] Trèves, François (1980), *Introduction to pseudodifferential and Fourier integral operators. Vol. 2: Fourier integral operators*, Plenum Press,MR0597145,  Zbl 0453.47027.

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri. Thanks but oscillatory integrals are discussed in Hörmander (1985), The analysis of linear partial differential operators. I, NOT part IV.  Please be more careful in the future to save readers' time.

Comment: Medo, there is a basic introductory part on oscillatory integrals in chapter 7, §7.8 pp. 236-240, in the first volume of Hörmander's treatise (2nd ed. 1989), where some elementary properties of these integrals are proved, but nothing concerning the asymptotic estimates . However, the core of the theory is developed in the fourth volume: I suggested to have a look at it because it is probably where one has to look for precise/exact estimates of the phase, not in volume I.

Comment: However, you remembered me about another possible source for this information: I'll check it later.

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri I do not know you and I definitely do not remember you :).  Part IV of Hormander does not contain any discussion of the asymptotic in the question. Equations (7.7.1) and (7.7.1') in part 1 give an answer.

Comment: Medo, I apologize for my band English (I should have said that reading your comment I remembered smtg. but as usual I messed up). I am glad to know that you’ve found an answer: the reference I remembered is the second volume of the treatise of V. Arnol’d et al “*Singularities of differentiable maps*”: chapter 6 deals mainly with asymptotic estimates of the behavior of oscillating integrals as the parameter $\lambda$ goes $\infty$. However it seems that they deal mostly with the case where the phase is stationary. 

Comment: non ti preoccupare. grazie mille per le tue risposte. buona serata.